# Sharp Super Scientific EL-9000 English Manual

Tags: sharp-el9000

I have a Sharp Super Scientific EL-9000 calculator (that used to be my mom's back in the day) which came with a Korean manual. I am a Korean American, and I can't understand the manual well. Does anybody have access to an English one? The format doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look for EL-5200 (not EL-5200X - which is related but different - like the whole 9x00 series) as well, as that's (AFAIK) the very same model. A quick search revealed [a page with some handling information](http://www.gelhaus.net/cgi-bin/page.py?loc:8bit/%20content:EL-5200.html) maybe good for first steps (and cross referencing to your Korean manual).

In addition, here's a [French manual](http://pockemul.com/Documents/9000.pdf) and the [service manual](https://sharppocketcomputers.com/4HK7JnFJDuVm/Service/ce50p_service_manual.pdf) for the printer/cassette interface CE-50P  - quite helpful if you want to hack some interface to modern devices. Heck, there's even a book describing it's [use for statistics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0030927269).

Comment: Thanks for the information! I don't have the printer, though.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the English manual: [Sharp EL-9000](http://basic.hopto.org/basic/manual/Sharp%20EL-9000%20EN.pdf).

Comment: [Archived on the Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20200601213256/http://basic.hopto.org/basic/manual/Sharp%20EL-9000%20EN.pdf) Link-only answers should be avoided where possible, but where unavoidable (e.g. here) you should try to archive the links, to prevent link rot. (Actually, you should do that anyway.)